# How to load xml of site with shabang(#) url

Tags: php, xml, function

How can load data of site such

```
 www.site.com/pageone#!/column/all/end
```

This urls cant load with simplexml_load_file() in php.

Comment: Echoing this function with url dont working ,
simplexml_load_file()
Error is => parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

Comment: As far as I am aware the problem is with xml contents not with the url you are talking about..

Comment: As a general rule HTML5 is **not** valid XML so you should try using the DOM document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls with hash bangs (#!) usually contain dynamic content - typically content that is ajaxed in.

This means, even if you did manage to load the page content, you probably would not have the full expected content.

With that said...

Urls must begin with `http://` (or `https://` if secure url).

and

The webpage must be valid XML.